# How to modify using a monadic function with lenses?

Tags: haskell, monads, haskell-lens

I needed a *lens* function that works like `over`, but with monadic operations:

```
overM :: (Monad m) => Lens s t a b -> (a -> m b) -> (s -> m t)
```

While this function is easy to define (it's actually just an identity modulo `WrappedMonad`), I wonder are such functions defined somewhere in *lens*?

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Lens

overF :: (Functor f) => Lens s t a b -> (a -> f b) -> (s -> f t)
overF l = l

overM :: (Monad m) => Lens s t a b -> (a -> m b) -> (s -> m t)
overM l = (unwrapMonad .) . l . (WrapMonad .)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in Control.Lens.Traversal:

```
traverseOf :: Over p f s t a b -> p a (f b) -> s -> f t
traverseOf = id

mapMOf :: Profunctor p =>
     Over p (WrappedMonad m) s t a b -> p a (m b) -> s -> m t
mapMOf l cmd = unwrapMonad #. l (WrapMonad #. cmd)
```

Example:

```
Prelude Control.Lens> traverseOf _1 (Just . (+2)) (2,2)
Just (4,2)

Prelude Control.Lens> mapMOf _1 (Just . (+2)) (2,2)
Just (4,2)
```

Comment: `traverseOf` is just `id`, it won't help with AMP problems. You need to have your `WrappedMonad`-fixed lens in order to make use of `traverseOf`.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson Thanks for the clarification, added `mapMOf` definition from the Traversal library.

Comment: is it possible to use biplate with monadic functions?