# Monadic alteration to tuple

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I am looking for a function with type similar to:

```
Monad m => (a, b) -> (b -> m c) -> m (a, c)
```

It appears to me as some combination of bind (`>>=`) and a lens operation.

I am aware that I can solve this with a pattern match after a bind, but my gut tells me there is a "simpler" way to write this by leveraging lenses.

Is there any such operation?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use a lens operation? It's simple enough using `do` notation: `doit (a,b) func = do { c <- func b; return (a,c) }`

Comment: Lenses came to mind because I'd be interested in solving this in the general sense-- that is abstracting out the shape, in this case 2-tuple.

Comment: Perhaps this SO question will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209982/how-to-modify-using-a-monadic-function-with-lenses

Comment: Don't know how I missed that! I'm marking an answer below correct as it was a direct solution to what I asked. Your link was certainly more what I was hoping to find though, thanks!

Comment: If your `Monad`s aren't `Applicative` yet, you might want to upgrade GHC. It's nice not to have to monkey around with that silly wrapper.

Comment: They most definitely are. To which wrapper are you referring?

Comment: `Applicative` and even `Functor` weren't superclasses of `Monad` till `base 4.8` (GHC 7.10). In the bad old days of last year, people had to use a newtype wrapper to turn arbitrary monads into applicatives.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is definitely lensy. The monad is actually just a bit of a distraction because all you need is a functor:

```
changesecond (a, b) f = fmap (a,) (f b)
```

I'm pretty sure the `_2` lens can be made to do your bidding with a basic lens thing like maybe `over` but I'm not too familiar with the library yet.

#### Edit

No combinator is really needed. You can write

```
changesecond pair f = _2 f pair
```

You should be able to work this out from the general definition of the `Lens` type.

#### Edit 2

This simple example demonstrates the main theme of Van Laarhoven lens construction:

1. Extract the focus from the context.
2. Apply the given function to produce a functorful of results.
3. Use `fmap` to restore the contexts to the results.

Ed Kmett's `lens` library elaborates on this theme in various ways. Sometimes it strengthens the functor constraint. Sometimes it generalizes the function to a profunctor. In the case of `Equality`, it removes the functor constraint. It just turns out that the same basic type shape can express a lot of different ideas.

Comment: Right you are. I must dig a bit deeper into the lens types. I should have immediately noticed the Functor aspect of the Lens definition. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Isn't that just: `changesecond = flip _2`?

Comment: Instead of invoking the `_2` lens directly, I'd suggest using `traverseOf`: `changesecond = flip (traverseOf _2)`. While [`traverseOf = id`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22210866/1333025), it makes the code somewhat more readable.

Answer (score 6):

Your function is just `forM = flip mapM`, or `for = flip traverse` if you relax the `Monad` constraint to `Applicative`. The `Functor` being traversed is `(,) a`.

```
Prelude> let foo :: Applicative f => (a, b) -> (b -> f c) -> f (a, c); foo p k = traverse k p
Prelude> :t foo
foo :: Applicative f => (a, b) -> (b -> f c) -> f (a, c)
Prelude> foo (1,2) (\x -> [x,2*x])
[(1,2),(1,4)]
```

(Also, as dfeuer points out, you don't even need `Applicative` in this specific case.)

Comment: Note that `flip traverse` is [`for`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html#v:for).