# Modify state using a monadic function with lenses

Tags: haskell, monads, lenses

My question is quite similar to [How to modify using a monadic function with lenses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209982/how-to-modify-using-a-monadic-function-with-lenses) The author asked if something like this exists

```
overM :: (Monad m) => Lens s t a b -> (a -> m b) -> s -> m t
```

The answer was [mapMOf](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-9.3/lens-4.15.4/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#v:mapMOf)

```
mapMOf :: Profunctor p =>
     Over p (WrappedMonad m) s t a b -> p a (m b) -> s -> m t
```

I'm trying to implement a function that modifies state in `MonadState` using a monadic function:

```
modifyingM :: MonadState s m => ASetter s s a b -> (a -> m b) -> m ()
```

Example without `modifingM`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Main where

import Control.Lens (makeLenses, use, (.=))
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy (StateT(StateT), execStateT)

data GameObject = GameObject
  { _num :: Int
  } deriving (Show)

data Game = Game
  { _objects :: [GameObject]
  } deriving (Show)

makeLenses ''Game

makeLenses ''GameObject

defaultGame = Game {_objects = map GameObject [0 .. 3]}

action :: StateT Game IO ()
action = do
  old <- use objects
  new <- lift $ modifyObjects old
  objects .= new

modifyObjects :: [GameObject] -> IO [GameObject]
modifyObjects objs = return objs -- do modifications

main :: IO ()
main = do
  execStateT action defaultGame
  return ()
```

This example works. Now I'd like to extract the code from `action` to a generic solution `modifingM`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Main where

import Control.Lens (makeLenses, use, (.=), ASetter)
import Control.Monad.State.Class (MonadState)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class (lift)
import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy (StateT(StateT), execStateT)

data GameObject = GameObject
  { _num :: Int
  } deriving (Show)

data Game = Game
  { _objects :: [GameObject]
  } deriving (Show)

makeLenses ''Game

makeLenses ''GameObject

defaultGame = Game {_objects = map GameObject [0 .. 3]}

modifyingM :: MonadState s m => ASetter s s a b -> (a -> m b) -> m ()
modifyingM l f = do
  old <- use l
  new <- lift $ f old
  l .= new

action :: StateT Game IO ()
action = modifyingM objects modifyObjects

modifyObjects :: [GameObject] -> IO [GameObject]
modifyObjects objs = return objs -- do modifications

main :: IO ()
main = do
  execStateT action defaultGame
  return ()
```

This results in compile time errors:

```
Main.hs:26:14: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Data.Functor.Identity.Identity s’
                     with ‘Data.Functor.Const.Const a s’
      Expected type: Control.Lens.Getter.Getting a s a
        Actual type: ASetter s s a b
    • In the first argument of ‘use’, namely ‘l’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: old <- use l
      In the expression:
        do { old <- use l;
             new <- lift $ f old;
             l .= new }
    • Relevant bindings include
        f :: a -> m b (bound at app/Main.hs:25:14)
        l :: ASetter s s a b (bound at app/Main.hs:25:12)
        modifyingM :: ASetter s s a b -> (a -> m b) -> m ()
          (bound at app/Main.hs:25:1)

Main.hs:31:10: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘IO’ with ‘StateT Game IO’
      Expected type: StateT Game IO ()
        Actual type: IO ()
    • In the expression: modifyingM objects modifyObjects
      In an equation for ‘action’:
          action = modifyingM objects modifyObjects
```

What's the problem?

---

**Edit 1:** Assign `new` instead of `old` value.

**Edit 2:** Added example with solution of @Zeta that does not compile.

**Edit 3:** Remove example of second edit. It didn't compile due to wrong imports (see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112354/modify-state-using-a-monadic-function-with-lenses/46113439#comment79190395_46113439)).

Comment: You can get rid of the edit, sorry, I missed that you've used `Control.Monad.Trans.State (StateT,put,get)`, not `Control.Monad.State (StateT,put,get)`.

Comment: @Zeta I have removed the example of the edit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're using `use` on a `ASetter`, but `use` takes a `Getter`:

```
use  :: MonadState s m => Getting a s a        -> m a 
(.=) :: MonadState s m => ASetter s s a b -> b -> m ()
```

Unfortunately, `ASetter` and `Getting` are not the same:

```
type Getting r s a   = (a -> Const r a ) -> s -> Const r s 
type ASetter s t a b = (a -> Identity b) -> s -> Identity t
```

We need to switch between `Const` and `Identity` arbitrarily. We need a `Lens`:

```
type Lens s t a b = forall f. Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
```

Note that there is no `f` on the left-hand side. Next, we note that your `lift` is not necessary. After all, `f` already works in our target monad `m`; you had to use `lift` previously because `modifyObjects` was in `IO` and `action` was in `StateT Game IO`, but here we just have a single `m`:

```
modifyingM :: MonadState s m => Lens s s a a -> (a -> m b) -> m ()
modifyingM l f = do
  old <- use l
  new <- f old
  l .= old
```

That works! But it's likely wrong, since you probably want to set the *new* value in `l .= old`. If that's the case, we have to make sure that `old` and `new` have the same type:

```
--                                      only a here, no b
--                                       v v     v      v
modifyingM :: MonadState s m => Lens s s a a -> (a -> m a) -> m ()
modifyingM l f = do
  old <- use l
  new <- f old
  l .= new
```

Keep in mind that you need to `lift` `modifyObjects` though:

```
action :: StateT Game IO ()
action = modifyingM objects (lift . modifyObjects)
```

---

We could stop here, but just for some fun, let us have a look again at Lens:

```
type Lens s t a b = forall f. Functor f => (a -> f b) -> s -> f t
```

For any `a -> f b` you give me, I'll give you a new `s -> f t`. So if we just plug something in your objects, we have

```
> :t \f -> objects f
\f -> objects f
  :: Functor f => (GameObject -> f GameObject) -> Game -> f Game
```

Therefore, we just need some `MonadState s m => (s -> m s) -> m ()` function, but that's easy to achieve:

```
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy (get, put) -- not the Trans variant!

modifyM :: MonadState s m => (s -> m s) -> m ()
modifyM f = get >>= f >>= put
```

Note that you need to use `Control.Monad.State` from `mtl` instead of `Control.Monad.Trans.State`. The latter only defines `put :: Monad m => s -> StateT s m ()` and `get :: Monad m => StateT s m s`, but you want to use the `MonadState` variant from `mtl`.

If we put all things together, we see that `modifyingM` can be written as:

```
modifyingM :: MonadState s m => Lens s s a a -> (a -> m a) -> m ()
modifyingM l f = modifyM (l f)
```

Alternatively, we use the can use the lens functions, although that does not give us the insight that we can use `l f`:

```
modifyingM :: MonadState s m => Lens s s a a -> (a -> m a) -> m ()
modifyingM l f = use l >>= f >>= assign l
```

Comment: @Daniel thanks for the edit, unfortunately you killed some part of the answer ^^".

Comment: sorry, maybe we just posted at the same time. My apologies :/

Comment: No worries, [that's what revisions are for](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46113439/revisions). I completely missed the bad formatting

Comment: @Zeta Thanks, I updated my example. I like to assign the new value of course *blush*. I tried to use your suggested solution in my example, but it results in compile time errors (see edit 2).

Comment: @maiermic I threw away the `Lens` part, since I have to check it more thoroughly. But the other error stems from a missing `lift` in `action`. If you like the `>>=` style you can use `use l >>= f >>= assign l`.

Comment: @maiermic you've used `Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy`, where I used `Control.Monad.State.Lazy`. The former has `put` and `get` variants that only work on `StateT`, whereas the latter uses `MonadState`.

Comment: @Zeta Thanks, is it possible to do `lift` in `modifyingM` so that I don't have to use `lift` in `action`?

Comment: Just figured it out. The type is `modifyingM :: Monad m => Lens' s a -> (a -> m a) -> StateT s m ()` and a possible implementation is `modifyingM l f = use l >>= lift . f >>= assign l`. I misunderstood `MonadState` and got further confused by using the wrong modules before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153953/discussion-between-zeta-and-maiermic).